# How to disable anchor using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to disable anchor link depending on a condition if some data comes to that field it should work as a hyperlink and if that data does not come then the link should not be there?
Any ideas on this are welcome.

Answer (score 28):

> Case 1:

To disable:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents="none";
document.getElementById(id).style.cursor="default";
```

To enable:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents="auto";
document.getElementById(id).style.cursor="pointer";
```

> Case 2:

If you want the link to be gone (not just disable it):

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
```

to get it back:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display="block"; //change block to what you want.
```

> Case 3:

If you want to hide it preserving the space for it:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden";
```

To get it back:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
```

Comment: This is nice because it works in cases where you have an href or an onclick.

Comment: you rock to the mx Jahin Saab. This is the only solution that worked for me. Would love if someone can explain why the prop(disable...) method doesn't work for anchors.

Answer (score 21):

I couldn't make sense of your question body, so I'll answer your question's title...

> How to disable anchor using javascript ?

#### JavaScript

```
if (condition) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].removeAttribute('href');
}
```

#### jQuery

...because *everyone* uses it, right?

```
if (condition) {
    $('a').first().removeAttr('href');
}
```

Comment: I think *even jQuery* might fail with `removeAtt` :)

Comment: @thirtydot Whoops. I think I forgot an `r` :)

Comment: This also works with document.getElementById(_yourIdHere_).removeAttribute('href');

Answer (score 3):

with jQuery

```
if(!data){
  $('#linkID').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

with Prototype

```
if(!data){
  $('linkID').observe('click', function(event) { event.stop() });
}
```

Comment: Why not with another framework the OP didn't mention, such as MooTools? :P

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that you answered with library code when the OP didn't specify a library.

Comment: @alex yeah, i know to do it only with jQuery ;-)

Comment: Highest voted answer when the OP doesn't even mention jQuery... ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:check()">my link</a>

function check(){
var data =document.getElementById("yourdatafield").value;
if(data)
  window.location="your_link_location";

}
```

Comment: I wonder what will happen if data is null..

Comment: @Mithun :we can check that in the if statement if required

Answer (score -4):

With jQuery:

To disable:

```
$('#anchor_tag').attr("disabled", true);
```

To enable:

```
$('#anchor_tag').attr("disabled", false);
```

Comment: This wont work on Anchors.